# Taking multiple picture with camera using Ionic

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, camera

Our App has a requirement to take multiple images and then display them for upload after the user has finished, Is this possible with IOS and Android camera.  Not seeing any examples.
I have looked at many Cordova plugins, all seem to either support taking one image or selecting multiple from the gallery, not allowing taking multiple images with the camera.

If you have done this or know if this is possible, please help

Comment: You can use cordova-plugin-media-capture plugin

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [`cordova-plugin-media-capture`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media-capture/) plugin.This plugin provides access to the device's audio, image, and video capture capabilities.

> > **capture.captureImage**
> >
> > Start the camera application and return information about captured image files.
> >
> > navigator.device.capture.captureImage(
> >             CaptureCB captureSuccess, CaptureErrorCB captureError, [CaptureImageOptions options]
> >         );
> >
> > **Description**
> >
> > Starts an asynchronous operation to capture images using the device's camera application. The operation allows users to capture more than one image in a single session.
> >
> > The capture operation ends either when the user closes the camera application, or the maximum number of recordings specified by CaptureImageOptions.limit is reached. If no limit value is specified, it defaults to one (1), and the capture operation terminates after the user captures a single image.
> >
> > When the capture operation finishes, it invokes the CaptureCB callback with an array of MediaFile objects describing each captured image file. If the user terminates the operation before capturing an image, the CaptureErrorCB callback executes with a CaptureError object featuring a CaptureError.CAPTURE_NO_MEDIA_FILES error code.

**[Example](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture#example-1)**

```
  // capture callback
var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
    var i, path, len;
    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
        // do something interesting with the file
    }
};

// capture error callback
var captureError = function(error) {
    navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
};

// start image capture
navigator.device.capture.captureImage(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit:2});
```

Comment: Multiple Image capture on iOS won't work. It's said so in the documentation itself. **iOS Quirks - "The limit parameter is not supported, and only one image is taken per invocation."**